# How to assign only(200 ) success response to next request in JMeter

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, performance, jmeter-plugins, rest-api

here i'm facing one problem.in My JMeter script i am getting some response like this

```
{"error":"404","error_description":"The underlying provider failed on Open."}
{"error":"404","error_description":"Model state invalid."}
{"error":"200","error_description":"965458"}

this coming in Response data
```

So i want to assign only 200 response to my next request that is in another thread group(means next  request should only accept 200 other than this it should not. ). i used response assertion and set Response code is 200 so that is not working for me.is there any alternative way to do this stuff please tell me with simple demo.

Comment: If you are asking about stubbing the response, please check this out - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ptgram24/OGr7OAvwRYg/MmWH_R7wDwAJ

Comment: No not about stubbing the response

Comment: Could you improve the question so your intended workflow gets more clarity? What is it what you try to achieve? Why different thread groups? Example of your jmx?

Comment: Hi...Ray Oei
Here i am using 2 thread group Because one thread group consisting  100 users and other  Thread group consisting of 20 users  where form 1st thread group 100 Response are generating in that Response most of them 200  and other Response are 300, 404 like this so here i want  2nd Thread group only  accept "error: 200" response to   process the further step in Test plan is this possible....? please tell me .

Comment: By Using JSR223 Is these possible that if(error==200) then execute the result .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Extract this `error` value into a JMeter Variable using [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) configured like:

   - Variable Names: anything meaningful, i.e. `error`
   - JSON Path Expressions: `$.error`
2. Add [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage) after the first sampler and use `"${error}" == "200"` as the "Condition"
3. Put your "next" requests under the If Controller

[image]

Assuming everything goes well the requests which are If Controller's children will be executed only if `error` value will be `200`.

Comment: Hi.....Dmitri if it is in 2nd Thread Group the Json Exp won't work i think so....

Comment: You can convert `${error}` variable into a JMeter property using [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) like `${__setProperty(error,${error},)}`  and refer it in the If Controller in another Thread Group using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like `${__P(error,)}`. See [Knit One Pearl Two: How to Use Variables in Different Thread Groups](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/knit-one-pearl-two-how-use-variables-different-thread-groups) for more detailed explanation if needed